# Disambiguate recursive definition of template function

Tags: c++, templates

I am building a statically typed Matrix where all operations with matrices are typechecked. However, I am having issues when I want to do something that modifies the Matrix based on given number.

For instance, adding one column is trivial:

```
template<int A, int B>
Matrix<A,B+1> addOneCol(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return Matrix<A,B+1>();
}
```

However, adding N columns is way harder. Since is impossible to typecheck with a function that has a branch where the return type is not the expected (even if the branch condition guarantees it) I can only think about a recursive approach:

```
template<int A, int B, int Z>
Matrix<A,B+1> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return addOneCol(m1);
}

template<int A, int B, int Z>
Matrix<A,B+Z> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return addOneCol(addZCols<A,B,Z-1>(m1));
}

template<int A, int B>
Matrix<A,B+1> addOneCol(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return Matrix<A,B+1>();
}
```

However, this is overloading `addZCols` in the return type, what is not allowed and leads to an error saying that calling `addZCalls` is ambiguous and cannot chose one of the 2 candidates. And what I want is that the version wiht `B+1` is only called as the base case, so to speak, when `Z=1`.

Any idea about how to make this work or a different approach?

Comment: I've read the question several times, but still can't understand what the problem is.

Comment: @Evg the problem is that the code doesn't compile, the error is that it cannot disambiguate between Matrix<A,B+Z> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) and Matrix<A,B+1> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There may be a more efficient approach, but with the recursion solution that you proposed, [SFINAE](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/enable_if) can be used to disambiguate the two versions of the template function.

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <int A, int B>
struct Matrix {
    constexpr int rows() const { return A; }
    constexpr int cols() const { return B; }

    int data;
};

template<int Z, int A, int B, std::enable_if_t<Z == 0, int> = 0>
Matrix<A, B> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return m1;
}

template<int Z, int A, int B, std::enable_if_t<Z != 0, int> = 0>
Matrix<A,B+Z> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return addOneCol(addZCols<Z-1, A, B>(m1));
}

template<int A, int B>
Matrix<A,B+1> addOneCol(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return Matrix<A,B+1>();
}

int main() {
    Matrix<2, 2> m1;
    auto m2 = addZCols<3>(m1);

    static_assert(m2.rows() == 2, "check rows");
    static_assert(m2.cols() == 5, "check cols");

    return 0;
}
```

I have also offset the recursion limit by one for clarity and re-ordered the template parameters of `addZCols` to make it nicer to call, but it works just the same with your original signature.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion! I was not aware of SFINAE but I definitely was searching for some way of constraining the values of the template parameters. Out of curiosity, do you have any additional suggestion about how to face this problem? As you have noted it might be inefficient but I couldn't come to anything better that typechecks.

Comment: My intuition is that since these typechecks and template-base computations happen at compile-time, the runtime performance should actually be fine. Compilation times could go up though. To check this intuition, I would look at the assembly resulting from the program and check that this type checking did not introduce accidental overhead.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you could simply write the function template like this:

```
template<int A, int B, int Z = 1>
Matrix<A,B+Z> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return Matrix<A,B+Z>{};
}
```

and then use it like this:

```
Matrix<1,2> a = addZCols(Matrix<1,1>{});

Matrix<1,4> b = addZCols<1,1,3>(Matrix<1,1>{});
```

By default, the 3rd parameter is `1`, and so this function template can be used as `addOneCol`.

As @Evg points out, template parameters have the nice property that default arguments can appear in any order, so we could have the `Z` argument in the first position:

```
template<int Z = 1, int A, int B>
Matrix<A,B+Z> addZCols(Matrix<A,B> m1) {
    return Matrix<A,B+Z>{};
}
```

This allows you to make the call more conveniently, like this:

```
Matrix<1,2> a = addZCols(Matrix<1,1>{});

Matrix<1,4> b = addZCols<3>(Matrix<1,1>{});
```

Since only `Z` needs to be specified, as `A`, and `B` can be deduced from the `Matrix` argument.

Comment: Why not to make `Z` the first parameter and then write just `addZCols<3>(...)`?

Comment: That would be fine, except it couldn't have a default value then.

Comment: Why not? `A` and `B` can be deduced from `Matrix`, so you can add a default value to the first parameter.

Comment: Oh, that's right, I completely forget that template arguments could do that. thanks. Edited the answer.

Comment: Thank you for the alternative! Indeed it solves the problem in an easier way, however I was particularly looking for the way of dealing with recursion and ambiguity since I might needed in similar problems.